# Function that takes an input text, checks if it has certain elements, and returns an output value (JS)

Tags: javascript, function, input, output

I'm kind of new to JavaScript, and I hope someone can help me figure out how to develop an application that:

1. Takes a text value from an **HTML input** when pressing a button;
2. Check if that text value has certain syllables (e.g. if it has the syllables "ba", "ca", and "da" in it);
3. returns a value to the **HTML output** whether or not it has syllables.

Obs. HTML is no problem. My focus is on JS.

I know it sounds simple, but I would like at least a direction from where to start. I already realized that I will have to have at least two variables, one for the text value

```
const text = document.getElementById("name").value;
```

and another one for the syllables that I intend to check

```
constant syllable = ["ba", "ca", "da", "fa", "ra"];
```

Am I in the right direction? My problem starts when I try to write the functions. Anyway, I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's the right start. Then you can loop through the syllables, checking whether `text` contains each one. See [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: Look for the onclick event. That may be a good start. There are multiple ways to create functions on JS. Try the one traditional ´function name(...) {...}´ form. That should be a good start

Answer (score -1):

Your questions is a little vague, but I hope this answers it. I've included some explanation about how it all works.

```js
// You define a function using 'function <identifier>(){<functionbody>}' (generally)
function containsSyllables(text_value, syllables) {
    // parameters are set here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    let foundSyllable = false; // <-- keep track of whether or not we've found a matching syllable

    // this loops through each item in `syllables` (we refer to each item as `syllable`)
    for (let syllable of syllables) { 

        // You can use the String.prototype.includes(substring) method to check if a string contains a substring
        if (text_value.includes(syllable)) {
            foundSyllable // <-- keep track that we've found a syllable in the text_value
            break // exit this loop if we found a matching syllable
        }

    }
    return foundSyllable
    // return the variable that kept track of whether or not we found a syllable 
}

var result = containsSyllables("bad", ["ca", "ba"]);
console.log(`"bad" contains "ca" or "ba"? ${result}`);
// OUTPUTS: "bad" contains "ca" or "ba"? false
```

There are some improvements you could make to this function, but I think this gets the point across simply.

If there is a line in this that you do not understand, you can search up roughly what it is: e.g. "for loop javascript". Look for a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) link, they're the best.

Answer (score -1):

you can use find on array and includes in a string

```js
const syllable = ["ba", "ca", "da", "fa", "ra"];

validate = (word) => {
  if (!word) {
    return false;
  }
  let res = syllable.find(i => word.includes(i));
  return res ? true : false
}

console.log(validate("aadaa"))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take your element with `getElementById`, like you did, add `event` on it with a function `name.addEventListener('input', updateValue);` then check if your input `includes` one of your substrings from array and print a message as result ( check [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))

```js
const syllable = ["ba", "ca", "da", "fa", "ra"];

const name = document.getElementById("nameInput");
name.addEventListener('input', checkForSyllables);

function checkForSyllables(e) {
  const value = e.target.value;
  if (syllable.some(syllable => value.includes(syllable))) {
    console.log(value) // your word contains one of elements from array
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = value + " contains syllable";
  }
}
```

```html
<p> Name: </p>
<input type="text" id="nameInput" keyup="onKeyUp">

<p id="result" />
```